Do end of turn effects trigger if the creature dies before the end of turn?
If my opponent cast a board wipe and I flicker my Yorion, Sky Nomad to exile my board except itself. Do still get my creatures back at the end of the turn even though Yorion is dead?

As is common with M:tG questions, the post describes a more specific situation than the title, and the title can't really be answered generally. It depends on what "the creature" is, and what it says, and how it's therefore related to whichever "end of turn effect".

The permanents exiled by Yorion will return even if Yorion is no longer on the battlefield.
Yorion's ability exiles the permanents, and then creates a delayed triggered ability that returns those permanents to the battlefield. Once this delayed triggered ability is created, it exists independent of Yorion, so it will trigger and resolve even if Yorion is no longer around.
